# Segmentation fault on arm-linux-gnueabi libcurl multithread

Tags: c, arm, libcurl

I keep hitting into a segmentation fault while running this example from
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define NUMT 4

const char * const urls[NUMT]= {
  "https://curl.haxx.se/",
  "ftp://cool.haxx.se/",
  "https://www.cag.se/",
  "www.haxx.se"
};

static void *pull_one_url(void *url)
{
  CURL *curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
  curl_easy_perform(curl); /* ignores error */ 
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_t tid[NUMT];
  int i;
  int error;

  /* Must initialize libcurl before any threads are started */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  for(i = 0; i< NUMT; i++) {
    error = pthread_create(&tid[i],
                           NULL, /* default attributes please */ 
                           pull_one_url,
                           (void *)urls[i]);
    if(0 != error)
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't run thread number %d, errno %d\n", i, error);
    else
      fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d, gets %s\n", i, urls[i]);
  }

  /* now wait for all threads to terminate */ 
  for(i = 0; i< NUMT; i++) {
    error = pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d terminated\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I crossed compiled my code on a Ubuntu 14.04 with the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` cross-compiler.

And, I am using (static linked):

- libcurl (curl-7.38.0)
- openssl (1.0.1u)

Error message:

```
 Connected to cool.haxx.se (80.67.6.50) port 21 (#0)
* response reading failed
* Closing connection 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It works fine when its when the `curl()` call is from a single thread, but it throws an error when I try to call `curl()` from multiple threads.

Comment: Have you tried to look what is inside the core file with gdb ?

Comment: the code is deployed to an machine with arm processor. it works fine when i try to run it on the ubuntu 14.04 but goes into segmentation fault whenever i run it in the embedded system.

Comment: Get the `core` file and analyze it outside of the embedded system (on your own desktop for example). It is much more convenient like that and will give you some hints to track down the problem.